# How to download Docker CLI only for Windows 7

Tags: windows, docker, command-line-interface

I'm using Windows 7 Pro and have existing shared Docker engine running on a Linux. I would like to use my workstation (with development environment) to access shared Docker engine.

Does someone know how to retrieve Docker client only for Windows 7 ? I have no admin privilege, so I can't install Docker Toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Downloads have finally been published:

> - Mac CLI binaries are available at
>   https://download.docker.com/mac/static/stable/
> - Windows CLI (and daemon) binaries at https://download.docker.com/win/
> - Linux CLI packages are available for each distro as docker-cli (deb and rpm) packages: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/

From: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2281#issuecomment-947699400

Answer (score 3):

Older Clients can be found here https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/
And here a some newer Builds by Stefan Scherer (Docker employee) https://github.com/StefanScherer/docker-cli-builder.

Just download docker.exe and add it to your windows path variable.
Then set your DOCKER_HOST variable to define against which Docker daemon you want to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Although docker provides a REST-like API, there aren't many clients for it. A quick google turned up one on [github](https://github.com/jufis/docker-rest-client), but ymmv. Even if you did find one, you're likely to run into the same problems involved in running docker-ce locally anyway.

There are a handful of gui clients that you could run on that engine and access with a browser, but if you are specifically after a cli you're SOL with this.

If you have an ssh client (git bash, or putty, or something), and you can arrange to run a bastion container on the engine, then you could run a container to ssh into and use that as if it's your local machine. You'd still have to scp resources onto it, but you'll eventually have to solve that problem anyway. Something like:

```
sudo docker container run --interactive --tty -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock image
```

Where 'image' is a linux image with an ssh server and appropriate keys, git, and docker installed. You could mount a local volume for persistence, or you could just keep everything in git.